# How to show cpu percentage number in system tray (taskbar) on windows 11 (with free app)?

Tags: taskbar, windows-11

I am a new windows user. (come from Linux world).

I would like to show the real-time cpu percentage number (NOT a cpu graph) in system tray (taskbar) on windows 11.

How can I achieve this? Any free app is OK. I won't install any paid app.

Btw, I also need to show cpu temperature number in system tray. So far, I am using `Speccy`. But the number looks very ugly with a yellow foreground and black background. I am wondering If anyone can suggest an app which uses a black foreground and no background color. (transparent background color).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [on-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [softwarerecs.se],  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: You might ask "can this be done natively in Win 11?" Product recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: @Tetsujin if this is off-topic, where can I ask this kind of queestions? Can you suggest a website? Thanks a lot.

Comment: See DavidPostill's comment, above mine

Comment: @Tetsujin got it. Sorry that I missed it. I will try Software Recommendation stackexchange then. Thanks.

Comment: The free app you want is Task Manager minimized. It has been part of Windows before Windows XP to current and is the best free app out there for monitoring your system.

Comment: @John Thanks for your reply, but If you read my question in detail, I have clarified that I don't want a CPU graph with the words `NOT a cpu graph`. And I have put the word `Number` in the question title. To show a cpu graph, it's easy. But I want to show a number instead of a graph in taskbar. So far, I found https://www.hwinfo.com/download/ is very good tool and show nearly everything. I am using that tool for now if nobody can give a better choice. Cheers.

Comment: Task Manager minimized is most definitely NOT a graph.  Minimize it and it is a tiny square. Hover and it gives you a wealth of information, none of it a graph. I  DID read your question and I am in no way new to Windows.

Comment: @John Sorry that I am not a native English speaker. All I want is a number without a hover. Can you please let me know how to change my words to make iit clear? I don't want any diagram or graph or any kind. I want a true number display on taskbar. So far this can be achieved by using hwinfo. Thanks.

Comment: The question is closed so I cannot add anything.